# How to Read pending logs through Python on Solana?

Tags: web3.js, transactions

I almost tried but getting failed. I am trying to fetch pending transaction.
here is my code if anyone suggest that would be great.

```
uri = "wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:

    # Send subscription request
    await websocket.send(json.dumps({
           "jsonrpc": "2.0",
           "id": 1,
           "method": "logsUnsubscribe",
           "params": [0]
       }))

    isResp = await websocket.recv()
    responseData = json.loads(isResp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to follow the example at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/logssubscribe and the python example at https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/cd811558cdf7b0ed7cdf31bf522870dafd03ee8d/tests/integration/test_websockets.py#L81, so you can do:

```
uri = "wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:

    # Send subscription request
    await websocket.send(json.dumps({
           "jsonrpc": "2.0",
           "id": 1,
           "method": "logsSubscribe",
           "params": [
               {
                   "mentions": [ <ACCOUNT_THAT_YOU_CARE_ABOUT> ]
               },
               {
                   "commitment": "confirmed"
               }
            ]
       }))

    isResp = await websocket.recv()
    responseData = json.loads(isResp)

    # and later unsubscribe
    await websocket.send(json.dumps({
           "jsonrpc": "2.0",
           "id": 1,
           "method": "logsUnsubscribe",
           "params": [responseData["result"]] # pass in the subscription id
       }))
```